# Advance search in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-query-language

Need to accomplish below task, not getting any suitable work around, pls help.

Data as below

```
   A     |  B  |
1  SAM     24
2  John    32
3  Jose    34
4  Samsung 36
```

I have created a search box using query, such that any keyword entered will match the Column A and return all the matching rows in list. In my case if SAM is searched, query will display SAM and SAMSUNG both. Formula is as under,

```
=QUERY([*RANGE*], "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "&"AND LOWER(F) LIKE LOWER(""%" &JOIN("%"") AND LOWER(F) LIKE LOWER(""%", SPLIT([*INPUT CELL*]," "))&"%"")",1)
```

However I want if the Input is 'SAM JOHN', it must return all the rows that contains these words instead it shows N/A error as per my current formula.

Any work around will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have **SAM JOHN** in `D1` cell. Then use below formula in `D2` cell.

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"select * where lower(A) matches '" & LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","|"))& "'")
```

[image]

Comment: It is working as required but earlier feature is gone which also displayed Samsung on the input of SAM. Is it achievable?

Comment: So, you also need to return Samsung for SAM?

Comment: Yes, that would be more convenient

Comment: Any suggestions?